# Updating to civi 4.6 after this can't create new emails no text editor

Tags: civimail, ckeditor, javascript, upgrade

After upgrading I can't create new emails. Also the menu bar is not showing right. Please look at my screen shots. step 1 and step2. Maybe a problem with javasript?

Help is urgently needed since we can't use the email function. *Moderator: Please don't put me on hold again.

Thanks

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

Comment: which version of 4.6 are you now on? the latest?

Comment: actually i can just make out your screenshot says you are on 4.6.2 not on 4.6.4. Can you please upgrade to the latest and then retest.

Comment: Hi petednz thanks a lot for comment. I did upgrade to 4.6.4 but still have the same effect. I have the information that this issue was actually resolved. Could anyone provide some information how to solve this bug? Best Piewo

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: The problems is K2. k2.php was not correct coded.

See plugins/system/k2.php - specifically this code section:

if (JString::strpos($response, 'prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"') === false) 
                    { 
                            $searches[] = ''; 
                            $replacements[] = 'http://ogp.me/ns#" '; 
                            $replacements[] = 'http://ogp.me/ns#">'; 
                    }

Change this to:

$app =& JFactory::getApplication(); 
            if ($app->isSite()){

```
                if (JString::strpos($response, 'prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"') === false) 
                { 
                        $searches[] = '<html '; 
                                $searches[] = '<html>'; 
                        $replacements[] = '<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" '; 
                        $replacements[] = '<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">'; 
                } 
        }
```

Thanks to "plethoradesign"

Now the editor appears but somehow all drop down box options are not clickable meaning you can't select a group nor templates and also you can't jump to the next step. Help is still needed. Best P

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new mailing on the demo, you see a url like:

http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/a/#/mailing/2

This looks different to the url you are seeing. Try changing the url for your site to see if this helps (the last number is the id for the mailing so you'll need to find the next number for you)

Updated: I see that "new" automatically changes to the next number, for some reason your system is not finding the next number.